# PHP: Is there any way to protect my RSS feeds?

Tags: php, rss, feed

On my website I have a content that is also accessible through RSS feeds. Is there any way to protect these feeds?
I mean, is there any way to allow users to add these RSS feeds into their RSS readers but block it to my competitors (because now they can load my data through RSS and offer them straight to their own customers)?

Comment: Not really. How would you identify a competitor? But if they re-publish your RSS content, you can sue them.

Comment: Use authentication || don't serve private stuff in RSS, period.

Comment: You can't, and a lot of reader/services proxy your feed anyway.

Comment: Wrong tech choice I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

What you can do is maybe, depending on the content, make the source (you) recognizable.

Even then, it is possible that some customer *prefers* the convenience of using one of your competitors because they aggregate something else of more interest. If you thwarted that possibility (instead of just, say, adding 'by user984621' somewhere in the items), you *could* be perceived by those customers as the one who stands between them and what they want. While it's true that they wouldn't probably ever be *your* customers, why go out of your way to inconvenience them?

That said, you could use some sort of URL *identification* scheme, e.g.

```
http://yoursite.com/rss/58ee09937d51f3886dcd0c0ea91c053e/channel1/rss2.0.xml
```

and keep a log of RSS accesses by ID. That way you can monitor who's getting that data and even pull the plug selectively on some feeds. It is even possible (**but is it worth it?**) to automatically monitor such a situation, by monitoring the competitors' feeds. When a correlation appears, it is possible to progressively restrict what ID the feed came from.

Then just use the Andropov document scheme - automatically inject a telltale in half of the candidate feeds. If the telltale surfaces in the target feed, you know which of the halves it came from, and you have halved the number of candidate feeds. Repeat until only one candidate remains. The scheme can be delayed, but not defeated, by a collusion between more than one candidate; and maybe you can even inject an ID in *every single feed* (but they might get rewritten along the way).

At that point, if there is a license agreement connected to the feed, it is easy to obtain proof that it has been violated, and ask whoever did it to cease and desist. How far you want to go down that road... and whether it's really worth the trouble... only you can say.